# Как объявить кнопки в цикле? (Java)

Tags: java

Как объявить кнопки в цикле, динамически название переменной для каждой итерации, сохранить в массив и добавить в фрейм?

хочу избавиться от

```
JButton button0;
JButton button1;
JButton button2;
JButton button3;
JButton button4;
JButton button5;
JButton button6;
JButton button7;
JButton button8;
JButton button...

button0=new JButton("0");
button1=new JButton("1");
button2=new JButton("2");
button3=new JButton("3");
button4=new JButton("4");
button5=new JButton("5");
button6=new JButton("6");
button7=new JButton("7");
button8=new JButton("8");
button9=new JButton...
```

заодно добавить возможность объявлять разное количество кнопок.
если точнее не могу разобраться как правильно изменить имя в цикле

UPD. вродь бы что-то вышло

```
      int i = 0, n = 9;

      n++;
      JButton[] buttons = new JButton[n];
      n = n - 1;

      for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
         buttons[i] = new JButton("" + i);
         p1.add(buttons[i]);
      }
```

думаю как исправить нормально этот костыль ("" + i) ? или так оставить?

Comment: лучше в список добавить. или словарь. зависит от того, как кнопка будет искаться.... и будет ли.... а так да..... коллекция спасёт

Comment: List<Button> buttons = new ArrayList();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно объявить список и работать с ним.

```
List<JButton> buttons = new ArrayList();

for(int index = 0; index<10; index++)
  buttons.add(new JButton....);
```